# Installing SQL Server in Hard Drive or in Virtual Box. What is the Difference?

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine

just curious:
I see in my school that all instances of SQL Server ( and other programs) are installed in a Virtual Machine. Is there a reason to install software in a VM instead of directly into the machine's hard drive? I assume it may be a matter of faulty installation of software somehow affecting the host PC , while if there is a problem within the  VM, the VM can just be deleted and the problem disappears, without affecting the host. Is this it, or is there more to it?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, greatly contributes to answering my question.

Comment: Who can put his data on a virtual box , it w'll be virtual data

Comment: Your question close to be [**off topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) But yes, the reason is easier to duplicate a VM than reinstall all the software in a pc when things get wrong.

Comment: @Sami: you can always use a web browser within the VM to send the data to the real machine, where it can become "Real Data".

Comment: Sending not like store it

Comment: @Sami: I agree that it would be virtual data, stored in the VHD, but what is your larger point?

Answer (score 1):

From a lab administrator's standpoint, it would be *FAR* easier to administrate multiple VMs in a classroom/lab setting.

Here is one great example (among others):

At the start of the semester, the admin can make a clean install (new OS, new SQL Server, etc.) on a new VM.  Once the machine has everything needed, he can take a snapshot of the VM.  After that, he can assign you to use that VM to your heart's content:  Create DBs, install games, infect the OS, whatever.

When you have finished your studies, the admin can then easily apply the snapshot, and, voila, the VM is back to the original state as when it was given to you earlier.  No reformatting, no uninstalling, etc.

Also equally compelling:  From that one initial VM image, an admin can clone as many VM copies as needed (one step) without having to go through the minutae of installing/configuring software over and over.